# Ubuntu Server. Nvidia 3060 never reaching P0/P1 performance state (no max clock)

Tags: server, nvidia, 22.04

I have multiple ubuntu 22.04 servers with different NVIDIA cards, but none of them ever reaches higher than P2 power state and with this never reaches max clock speed.

I have tried a lot but nothing seems to convince the card to go higher.

```
    root@pod0003:~# nvidia-smi -q -a                                                     
                                                                                         
    ==============NVSMI LOG==============                                                
                                                                                         
    Timestamp                                 : Fri Jan 27 19:00:11 2023                 
    Driver Version                            : 525.78.01                                
    CUDA Version                              : 12.0                                     
                                                                                         
    Attached GPUs                             : 1                                        
    GPU 00000000:05:00.0                                                                 
        Product Name                          : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060                  
        Product Brand                         : GeForce                                  
        Product Architecture                  : Ampere                                   
        Display Mode                          : Disabled                                 
        Display Active                        : Disabled                                 
        Persistence Mode                      : Enabled                                  
        MIG Mode                                                                         
            Current                           : N/A                                      
            Pending                           : N/A                                      
        Accounting Mode                       : Disabled                                 
        Accounting Mode Buffer Size           : 4000                                     
        Driver Model                                                                     
            Current                           : N/A                                      
            Pending                           : N/A                                      
        Serial Number                         : N/A                                      
        GPU UUID                              : GPU-1fbe1409-48f9-577f-c063-1e5d895d900b 
        Minor Number                          : 0                                        
        VBIOS Version                         : 94.06.4D.00.1B                           
        MultiGPU Board                        : No                                       
        Board ID                              : 0x500                                    
        Board Part Number                     : N/A                                      
        GPU Part Number                       : 2544-302-A1                              
        Module ID                             : 1                                        
        Inforom Version             
       Image Version                     : G001.0000.94.01  
       OEM Object                        : 2.0              
       ECC Object                        : N/A              
       Power Management Object           : N/A              
   GPU Operation Mode                                       
       Current                           : N/A              
       Pending                           : N/A              
   GSP Firmware Version                  : N/A              
   GPU Virtualization Mode                                  
       Virtualization Mode               : None             
       Host VGPU Mode                    : N/A              
   IBMNPU                                                   
       Relaxed Ordering Mode             : N/A              
   PCI                                                      
       Bus                               : 0x05             
       Device                            : 0x00             
       Domain                            : 0x0000           
       Device Id                         : 0x254410DE       
       Bus Id                            : 00000000:05:00.0 
       Sub System Id                     : 0x397D1462       
       GPU Link Info                                        
           PCIe Generation                                  
               Max                       : 4                
               Current                   : 4                
               Device Current            : 4                
               Device Max                : 4                
               Host Max                  : 4                
           Link Width                                       
               Max                       : 16x              
               Current                   : 16x              
       Bridge Chip                                          
           Type                          : N/A              
           Firmware                      : N/A              
       Replays Since Reset               : 0                
       Replay Number Rollovers           : 0                
       Tx Throughput                     : 32000 KB/s       
       Rx Throughput                     : 95000 KB/s       
       Atomic Caps Inbound               : N/A              
       Atomic Caps Outbound              : N/A              
   Fan Speed                             : 42 %             
   Performance State                     : P2         
   Clocks Throttle Reasons                            
       Idle                              : Not Active 
       Applications Clocks Setting       : Not Active 
       SW Power Cap                      : Not Active 
       HW Slowdown                       : Not Active 
           HW Thermal Slowdown           : Not Active 
           HW Power Brake Slowdown       : Not Active 
       Sync Boost                        : Not Active 
       SW Thermal Slowdown               : Not Active 
       Display Clock Setting             : Not Active 
   FB Memory Usage                                    
       Total                             : 8192 MiB   
       Reserved                          : 218 MiB    
       Used                              : 5886 MiB   
       Free                              : 2087 MiB   
   BAR1 Memory Usage                                  
       Total                             : 8192 MiB   
       Used                              : 7 MiB      
       Free                              : 8185 MiB   
   Compute Mode                          : Default    
   Utilization                                        
       Gpu                               : 100 %       
       Memory                            : 91 %       
       Encoder                           : 0 %        
       Decoder                           : 0 %        
   Encoder Stats                                      
       Active Sessions                   : 0          
       Average FPS                       : 0          
       Average Latency                   : 0          
   FBC Stats                                          
       Active Sessions                   : 0          
       Average FPS                       : 0          
       Average Latency                   : 0          
   Ecc Mode                                           
       Current                           : N/A        
       Pending                           : N/A        
   ECC Errors                                         
       Volatile                                       
           SRAM Correctable              : N/A        
           SRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A        
           DRAM Correctable              : N/A        
           DRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A        
       Aggregate                                      
           SRAM Correctable              : N/A        
           SRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A        
           DRAM Correctable              : N/A        
           DRAM Uncorrectable            : N/A        
   Retired Pages                                      
       Single Bit ECC                    : N/A        
       Double Bit ECC                    : N/A        
       Pending Page Blacklist            : N/A        
   Remapped Rows                         : N/A        
   Temperature                                        
       GPU Current Temp                  : 62 C       
       GPU Shutdown Temp                 : 98 C       
       GPU Slowdown Temp                 : 95 C       
       GPU Max Operating Temp            : 93 C       
       GPU Target Temperature            : 83 C       
       Memory Current Temp               : N/A        
       Memory Max Operating Temp         : N/A        
   Power Readings                                     
       Power Management                  : Supported  
       Power Draw                        : 118.71 W   
       Power Limit                       : 170.00 W   
       Default Power Limit               : 170.00 W   
       Enforced Power Limit              : 170.00 W   
       Min Power Limit                   : 100.00 W   
       Max Power Limit                   : 170.00 W   
   Clocks                                             
       Graphics                          : 1957 MHz   
       SM                                : 1957 MHz   
       Memory                            : 7300 MHz   
       Video                             : 1717 MHz   
   Applications Clocks                                
       Graphics                          : N/A        
       Memory                            : N/A        
   Default Applications Clocks                        
       Graphics                          : N/A        
       Memory                            : N/A        
   Deferred Clocks                                                            
       Memory                            : N/A                                
   Max Clocks                                                                 
       Graphics                          : 2130 MHz                           
       SM                                : 2130 MHz                           
       Memory                            : 7501 MHz                           
       Video                             : 1950 MHz                           
   Max Customer Boost Clocks                                                  
       Graphics                          : N/A                                
   Clock Policy                                                               
       Auto Boost                        : N/A                                
       Auto Boost Default                : N/A                                
   Voltage                                                                    
       Graphics                          : 1081.250 mV                        
   Fabric                                                                     
       State                             : N/A                                
       Status                            : N/A                                
   Processes                                                                  
       GPU instance ID                   : N/A                                
       Compute instance ID               : N/A                                
       Process ID                        : 9165                               
           Type                          : G                                  
           Name                          : /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 
           Used GPU Memory               : 5 MiB                              
       GPU instance ID                   : N/A                                
       Compute instance ID               : N/A                                
       Process ID                        : 9902                               
           Type                          : C                                  
           Name                          : /home/tk/jupyter/panenv/bin/python 
           Used GPU Memory               : 2938 MiB
```

As can be seen in this log, there is no Throttle reason active. Yet I am stuck in Performance state P2 with clock speeds:

```
   Graphics                          : 1957 MHz   
   SM                                : 1957 MHz   
   Memory                            : 7300 MHz   
   Video                             : 1717 MHz
```

While max would be:

```
   Graphics                          : 2130 MHz                           
   SM                                : 2130 MHz                           
   Memory                            : 7501 MHz                           
   Video                             : 1950 MHz
```

Most notably I tried:

```
X :0 &                                          
export DISPLAY=:0                               
nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1"
```

But to no avail.

I use this card for tensorflow model training. The system is an Ryzen 12 core on an Gigabyte B550 with resizable bar enabled and PCIe gen 4, which can be seen is being used just fine. The power supply is 750 Watt

According to [NVIDIA](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__gpupstate.html) the P states mean this:

```
P0/P1 - Maximum 3D performance
P2/P3 - Balanced 3D performance-power
P8 - Basic HD video playback
P10 - DVD playback
P12 - Minimum idle power consumption
```

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across [this](https://babeltechreviews.com/nvidia-cuda-force-p2-state/):

> Official Background on NVIDIA ‘CUDA – Force P2 State’ We asked NVIDIA
> about this feature and they replied:
>
> […] Basically, we added this p-state because running at max memory
> clocks for some CUDA applications can cause memory errors when running
> HUGE datasets. Think DL apps, oil exploration use cases, etc where you
> are crunching large numbers and it would error out with full memory
> clocks. These are the types of apps you really shouldn’t be running on
> GeForce anyway but since there are a lot of folks who do and were
> running into this issue we created this new mode for them.

So in the end this is a stability tradeoff that should be accepted.